Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok satus. Using Angular 18
I am using ASP.NET framework with Angular 18. I am trying to delete a row but whenever I try to delete, I get this error:

Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status

I had tried all the ways to enable Cors or to use proxy.config.json file - but nothing worked.
Fyi the project gets the data normally but the problem appears in delete


I have tried all possible ways in the backend; I tried to enable Cors in my web.config and global.asax
In Angular I tried proxy file

Not sure if the error is due to not having permission to access the route, or you are getting an exception when entering deleteEvalutation.  I would put a breakpoint in deleteEvaluation to determine which is occurring.

thank you for Responding on my Question  really appreciate it
there is no any permission to access the  rout as there is another method of type Get
it retrieves the data normally  i tried many ways but i dont know what i ma doing wrong
and i tried to add a breakpoint but does not go to the api in backend

I still don't know if the issue is with the route or the query is failing.

me too i haven't found ana exact way to solve this issue ...
but i opened chrome in Cors disable mode  and went to the breakpoint in backend and worked well

Try making connection with Postman.  Postman is very robust and will add extra http header that are not added in c#.  It may be the User Agent header.  If Postman works, than in the Postman Control Panel you can get the entire HTTP request including all the HTTP header.  Than add the missing headers to you c# code.

i will do that thank you for your Help :)

URL of the request doesn't look right to me... maybe try adding the port to the request or just making it relative. Seems like the  request the browser is sending is either getting redirected or rejected by the server?

you should check your server for anything set globally for all verbs (maybe it's trying to authorize OPTIONS verb?)  or any global redirects... also be sure OPTIONS is an allowed verb.

You might want to include your program.cs file to confirm cors settings are correct (and in correct order)

Very Well i will try to Do what you are saying thank you alot

In CORS mechanism , the browser makes an "Option" called request  "preflight"  to your method ,if the response will "200- OK" the the browser continues with the main request  if it fails , then the CORS error will be raised.
So in your case there might be an exception in your action that makes the preflight request fail. you can also use postman to make your request and trace it from the beginning of request pipeline to spot the problem .

Okay Hamid Thank you i will try this

try
[Route("api/EvaluationSetup/deleteEvaluation/{evalCode}]
[HttpDelete]
public HttpResponseMessage deleteEvaluation(int evalCode) { ... }

And call it from angular as
this.httpClient.delete('api/EvaluationSetup/deleteEvaluation/10')


thanks Elsieo i going to try this either
